# CSS Drop Down Menu Fading Without Javascript

Tags: html, css

I was trying to do some fading effects with Javascript but it was giving me some issues. I've managed to get my drop down menu working entirely with CSS, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to get the menu to fade in / out when hovering over it's parent for some reason.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wLp2z1w/1/)

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="header1">
<table width="100%" height="60px" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><ul id="horiznav">
    <li><a href="#" class='class2'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class='class2'>Statistics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class='class2'>Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class='class2'>Lists</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class='class2'>All Active Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='class2'>By Phase</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='class2'>By User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='class2'>Completed Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class='class2'>New Project</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class='class2'>Administration</a></li>
  </ul></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#header1{
    background: #0d2965;
    background-color: #0d2965;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
}

ul#horiznav, #horiznav ul{/*remove the bullets from the dropdown ul as well*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:32px;
    text-align:center
}

#horiznav li{
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*//*float the li element so the menu's horizontal...*/
    width:150px;/*...and set the width*/
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;/*set position:relative as the start point for absolutely positioning the dropdown*/
}

#horiznav li a{
    display:block;/*make the link a block element...*/
    width:150px;/*...with a fixed width...*/
    line-height:30px;/*...and set the line-height to vertically centre the text*/
    text-align:center;/*horizontally centre the text...*/
    color:white;/*...colour it white...*/
    text-decoration:none;/*...and remove the default underline*/
    background-color:#EA9531;/*give the link an orange background...*/
    border:1px solid white/*...and a white border...*/
}

#horiznav li a:hover{
    -webkit-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    color:#333333/*change the text colour on :hover*/
}

#horiznav li ul{
    display:none;/*hide the dropdown*/
    position:absolute;/*position it absolutely..*/
    left:0;/*...align the left edge with the left edge of the parent li...*/
    top:32px/*...and 32px down from the top - 30px height + 2px for the border*/
}

#horiznav li:hover ul {
    display:block/*display the ul when the parent li is hovered*/
}

#horiznav li ul a{
    background-color:#FFB33B/*give the dropdown a different background colour*/
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or links to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Transition` cant be used on the `display` property.

Use `visibility` and `opacity` instead.

**Use this CSS**

```
#horiznav li ul {
    -webkit-transition:visibility 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:visibility 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:visibility 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition:visibility 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:32px;
}

#horiznav li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

[Proof in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hestm001/6gakhrv0/)

Works fine for me.

Comment: I tried something similar to that, but it didn't appear to have the effect. http://jsfiddle.net/1wLp2z1w/2/

Comment: I've updated the code, it should work just fine now :). (this morning I was on my phone, couldn't test it back then)

Comment: That works great, thanks! 

What was it that fixed the issue? Was it the Opacity setting or the Visibility?